# Long to wide format with GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have been trying to figure out how to do the following with no success. I tried sampling, grouping ... got stuck.

I have the following pandas dataframe example:

```
date             |  price  |
09/09/2018 08:30 |  22.1   |
09/09/2018 08:35 |  22.12  |
09/09/2018 08:40 |  22.20  |
09/09/2018 08:45 |  22.13  |
09/09/2018 08:50 |  22.19  |
09/09/2018 08:55 |  22.39  |
```

I want to group the dates in 15 minutes and get the following dataframe.

```
date_15          |  price_1  |  price_2  |  price 3  |
09/09/2018 08:30 |   22.1    |   22.12   |   22.20   |
09/09/2018 08:45 |   22.13   |   22.19   |   22.39   |
```

Then I would set_index('date_15') and do a join which I can do myself.

Could you please help with the above?

Comment: This question could be better if you add the code from your attempt and explain in which way it didn't work.

Comment: @sobek, my attempts are irrelevant since they did not even come close to the required results. Thanks

Comment: That comment wasn't from me

Comment: My bad, fixed the typo.

Comment: Your attempts are by no means irrelevant because they show that you have made an effort and aren't just here to have someone else write code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `groupby` on the date every 15 minutes using the `pd.Grouper`, and then create a new DataFrame with the result:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce')
v = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='15min'))['price'].apply(list)

pd.DataFrame(v.tolist(), index=v.index).add_prefix('price ')

                     price 0  price 1  price 2
date                                          
2018-09-09 08:30:00    22.10    22.12    22.20
2018-09-09 08:45:00    22.13    22.19    22.39
```

Comment: Thanks! Apply takes a dataframe or series as input? The function is applied to each group?

Comment: @stoicky Both. Also, yes.